# Will the java compiler optimise calls to Math.exp with a constant?

Tags: java, performance, compiler-optimization

If I'm implementing a formula containing `1-Math.exp(-50)` and want the result to be performant should I pre-calculate that constant and save it in a `static final double` or is the Java compiler smart enough to realize that the result is a constant and pre-calculate it as it would do with something simpler like `1-50/7`?

Comment: Actually pre-computing tables of such functions is a common optimization in application that need to make heavy use of them. Like in cryptography where *log* and *exp* tables are used to efficiently compute large powers.

Comment: `1-Math.exp(-50)` is just `1.0`, no calculation necessary

Comment: @harold Technically it's 1-1.9287498e-22 - so not quite 1.0 ;)

Comment: @TimB technically [1-1.9287498e-22 = 1.0](https://ideone.com/MtlTpl)

Comment: @harold interesting, 1.9e-22 fits in double but when you subtract it from 1 that no longer does. That makes sense I guess, it doesn't answer the more general case though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The javac compiler does not pre-calculate the value (removed irrelevant code):

```
$ javap -v Main.class

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]) throws java.lang.Exception;
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=4, locals=3, args_size=1
         0: dconst_1
         1: ldc2_w        #2                  // double -50.0d
         4: invokestatic  #4                  // Method java/lang/Math.exp:(D)D
         7: dsub
         8: dstore_1
         9: getstatic     #5                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        12: dload_1
        13: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(D)V
        16: return
}
SourceFile: "Main.java"
```

Original source:

```
public final class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final double v = 1 - Math.exp(-50);
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the method implemented? Maybe the CPU has pre-computed tables.

Comment: That seems quite definitive, the call to Math.exp is in the generated bytecode. Thanks :)

Comment: Of course, it might be possible (do not know for sure) that the JIT will optimise it :) After all javac is pretty dumb and all optimisations are done during runtime.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev True enough, that's the sort of secret sauce I was hoping someone would unveil and that I just hadn't come across - it's similar to escape analysis really.

Answer (score 6):

> is the Java compiler smart enough to realize that the result is a constant

According to the Java Language Specification chapter on [constant expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), no. The expression `1-Math.exp(-50)` will not be evaluated at compile time.

Pre-calculate it if you have a reasonable reason to believe it'll cause performance loss. (Which I doubt if you store the result once in the `static` field and reuse it.)

---

The rules:

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive
>   type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using
>   only the following:
>
> - Literals of primitive type and literals of type String (§3.10.1,
>     §3.10.2, §3.10.3, §3.10.4, §3.10.5)
> - Casts to primitive types and casts to type String (§15.16)
> - The unary operators +, -, ~, and ! (but not ++ or --) (§15.15.3,
>     §15.15.4, §15.15.5, §15.15.6)
> - The multiplicative operators *, /, and % (§15.17)
> - The additive operators + and - (§15.18)
> - The shift operators <<, >>, and >>> (§15.19)
> - The relational operators <, <=, >, and >= (but not instanceof)
>     (§15.20)
> - The equality operators == and != (§15.21)
> - The bitwise and logical operators &, ^, and | (§15.22)
> - The conditional-and operator && and the conditional-or operator ||
>     (§15.23, §15.24)
> - The ternary conditional operator ? : (§15.25)
> - Parenthesized expressions (§15.8.5) whose contained expression is a
>     constant expression.
> - Simple names (§6.5.6.1) that refer to constant variables (§4.12.4).
> - Qualified names (§6.5.6.2) of the form TypeName . Identifier that
>     refer to constant variables (§4.12.4).